# Prevent multiple clicks globally

Tags: jquery

I am using this code block to prevent impatient customers from clicking numerous times and sending multiple requests to our server.

```
<script>
    function prevent_click() { 
        return false;
    }

    $('a, input[type=submit], input[type=button]').on('click', function(e) { 
        $(e.currentTarget).click(prevent_click); 

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(e.currentTarget).unbind('click', prevent_click);
        }, 3000);

    });
</script>
```

It blocks clicking events after the first click for 3 seconds but doing it for the same link, button, etc. How can I run this for all links, but not individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a flag to prevent default action this way:

```js
var preventClick = false;
$('a, input[type=submit], input[type=button]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('div').text( preventClick ? 'Click blocked' : 'Allowed' );
    if (preventClick) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        preventClick = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            preventClick = false;
        }, 3000);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">I am link</a>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" value="Button" />
<div>Click result...</div>
```

Please note it [stops propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), which:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovbw3e5k/).

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much @skobaljic

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try e.preventDefault() on all a href tags like this:

```
$('a').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don't want to prevent them completely. I want to to prevent them all, after first click for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you should disable button globally
Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function()
{
   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```